# Share mobile app with advertisers via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

everyone! I need to share my mobile app (that is in my facebook developer acc) with other ad accounts for them to advertise it. I understand how to do that in GUI (see the screenshot); however, I want to automize it.
I'm looking for the appropreate API and asked OpenAI - no luck. Maybe some one has already worked with that and can help me?

[Advertising Accounts Authorized ad account IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQmWu.png)

Here is endpoints that I've tried:

1. /act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/advertisable_applications
2. /act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/assigned_users
3. /act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/subscribed_ads
4. /act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/subscribed_apps
5. /<APP_ID>/authorized_adaccounts

Also I tried this one but it's won't do because of a lot of requirements
{business-id}/client_apps